# on animation end w/o using .animate();

Tags: jquery, css, ipad

I'm building a iPad web app. The .animate() method is much too slow to use which is why the majority of my transitions are done using css. How do I implement

html

```
<div id="myGallery" class="container"></div>
```

css

```
.container {
position: fixed;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

.pos-1 {
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
}

.pos-2 {
-webkit-transform:translate3d(100px,0px,0px);
}
.pos-3 {
-webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0px,0px);
}
```

js

```
$("#myGallery").removeClass("pos-" + this.previousId).addClass("pos-" + this.currentId);

$("#myGallery").bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function() {
        // this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        console.log("done animating");
    });
```

How do I use "webkitAnimationEnd" or rather how do I trigger "done animating" without resorting to using .animate()?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the class of the element from one which has an animation to one which doesn't?

Am I misunderstanding the question?

Do you mean the reverse? You want to know when the css animation is over? I assume you can do that by setting a timer and calculating in advance how long the animation should take.

Comment: It's not a reverse, it's should jump randomly from one position to another.

Answer (score 0):

1. `position:fixed` in iOS safari doesn't work. It would act like absolute; So don't use this property on iOS anymore as I'm doing same
2. You can do what are you trying to do with just CSS3 using [steps()](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-animations/#animation-timing-function) method.

Please don't use JavaScript aka jQuery here for doing animation in iOS. It never gave me good results.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen/mRLMF/1/) your code in pure CSS for animation.

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pos1{
    from{-webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0px,0px)}
    to{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px)}   
}
@-webkit-keyframes pos2{
    from{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px)}
    to{-webkit-transform:translate3d(100px,0px,0px)}   
}
@-webkit-keyframes pos3{
    from{-webkit-transform:translate3d(100px,0px,0px)}
    to{-webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0px,0px)}   
}


.container {
width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid gray;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0px,0px)
}
.pos1{
  -webkit-animation-name: pos1;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
 -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0px,0px,0px)
}

.pos2{
  -webkit-animation-name: pos2;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
 -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

    -webkit-transform:translate3d(100px,0px,0px)
}

.pos3{
  -webkit-animation-name: pos3;
 -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
 -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

    -webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0px,0px)
}
```

JQ

```
$('#p1').click(function(){
$('#myGallery').removeClass('pos1, pos2, pos3').addClass('pos1');
});
$('#p2').click(function(){
$('#myGallery').removeClass('pos1, pos2, pos3').addClass('pos2');
});
$('#p3').click(function(){
$('#myGallery').removeClass('pos1, pos2, pos3').addClass('pos3');
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="myGallery" class="container"></div>
<input type="button" value="pos1"  id="p1"/>
<input type="button" value="pos2"  id="p2"/>
<input type="button" value="pos3"  id="p3"/>
```

Comment: This was my solution before but the keyframes implied that I knew the position of where it was originally. In this answer, you would have to generate 6 keyframes for 3 position. Adding positions, exponentially increases the amount of keyframes. I've tried removing the "from" object but that didn't work.

Comment: As I told you you can just have onee keyframe and use Steps() to just animate part of you keyframe

Comment: Just read the documentation "animation-timing-function". The steps method assumes that the presets are in series, meaning you can only scrub through the points forwards or backwards. Assuming there are 6 steps (0%, 20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%), I'd like to jump around from say, 40% to 0% to 100% as an example